# How to add an onClick to a parent from within React Component whose Ref is passed to it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a Reusable Menu Component.

It takes an array of objects and generates the Menu based on the array sent as prop.

This menu will always be triggered on click.

Now what I wanted to do is have the onClick implementation(event listeners, onClick function, etc) inside the `Menu` component itself.

How I planned on doing it was assigning a `Ref` to whatever is the `Parent` of the menu(the element that needs to be clicked for the menu to show) and sending that ref down to `Menu` and using the `Ref` to attach the onClick function onto the parent.

**Parent.jsx**

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';

const Parent = () => {

   const menuRef = useRef(null);

   return(
     <>
       {/* 
         A lot of elements
       */}
       <ul type="none">
         <li>Some svg's in a list</li>
         .
         .
         .
         <li ref={menuRef}>
            <svg>Another svg...</svg>
            <Menu parentRef={menuRef} items={menu} />
       </ul>
     </>
   ) 

}
```

**Menu.jsx**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';

const Menu = ({parentRef,items}) => {
   const [isMenuActive, setMenuActive] = useState(false);
   
   const onParentClick = (e) => {
       // some code and then
       setMenuActive(!isMenuActive);
   }
   
   // This is what I intended to do
   parentRef.current.onClick(onParentClick);
   
   return(
     <div className={`menu-container ${isMenuActive ? 'active' : '' }`}
        {/*
              Menu population code
        */}
     </div>
   )

}
```

The problem is every function of `parentRef.current.*` is returning `null`.

A `console.log` of `parentRef` is yielding an object with the `current` havin the entire `<li>` tag as expected. But I am not getting how to assign an onClick onto it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why you wanna do it though? You can declare setMenuActive on parent and pass the isMenuActive prop from parent itself

Comment: @bugwheels94 true. But the menu is going to be used in a bunch of places and I would have to keep redefining the event handling boilerplate code everywhere.

Comment: I am pretty sure that you are not following the principles. Use children to reuse Menu components instead of using refs to reuse parents

Comment: @bugwheels94 I don't get it. What does 'using children to reuse Menu components' mean? I am pretty new to react, hence unaware of the principles. Could you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

function call: `parentRef.current.onClick(onParentClick)`

function assignment: `parentRef.current.onclick = function`

Comment: This throws  `null` on `parentRef.current.onclick`. Putting the entire statement inside a `useEffect(() => {},[])` however gets the flow started but the `onParentClick` is not updating the state of `isMenuActive` after the first click. I logged `isMenuActive` inside `onParentClick` and it always stays false. Even if the first click is changing the state to true.